# How to run cron job 1 hr after GMT 00:00 hr daily

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I am new to ubuntu. I wants to run a cron job 1 hr after GMT 00:00 hr daily from my ubuntu machine.

I am using cron expression **00 01 * * ***

So here are the steps which I performed but not success with this.

**Step 1 :** Open crontab with command `crontab -e`

**Step 2 :** make entry of cron expression as below

`00 01 * * * /media/user1/Data/users/xyz/myjob.sh`

But my script job.sh is not running with given expression.

Comment: Anything in the cron log?

Comment: @ Anders R. Bystrup - Thanks for comment my .log file is generated on my specific time. So I think job is running on it's time. But log shows nothing and my job is also not perform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add this to first line of your script

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and configure permissions

```
chmod +x /media/user1/Data/users/xyz/myjob.sh
```

on the terminal screen.

I hope it helps.

Comment: @alitemel- Thanks, it resolve my issue. issue was a permission. It resolved by chmod +x /media/user1/Data/users/xyz/myjob.sh

Answer (score 1):

Verify if the script is running standalone.

`/media/user1/Data/users/xyz/myjob.sh`

Also verify if the crontab entry is added by executing

`crontab -l`